# How to parse multiple nodes of html using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'd appreciate if someone could help! I'm trying to parse the following page of Groupon website http://www.groupon.com/browse/chicago?category=activities-and-nightlife

```
  var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
  var deal1 = webGet.Load("http://www.groupon.com/browse/chicago?category=activities-and-nightlife");
```

I want to get the whole block of each Deal(i.e. offer for discount)

```
 HtmlNodeCollection content_block = deal1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class = 'deal-list-tile grid_5_third']");
```

Then out of each block i want to get title, company name, location and price.

```
foreach(HtmlNode node in content_block)
        {
             string title2 = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class = 'deal-title js-permalink']").InnerText;
            string country2 = node.SelectSingleNode("//p[@class = 'merchant-name']").InnerText;
            string location2 = node.SelectSingleNode("//p[@class = 'location']").InnerText;
            string price2 = node.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class = 'price']/span").InnerText;
        }
```

Here i get confused, i need to write all the information about deals into 
`DbSet<Deal> Deals` , but even if i try to display the content as `ViewBag.Message = title + country + location + price;` i get System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in the line with `content_block`.

What am i doing wrong =(
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the page you listed, I could not even find a class with that name [when I view the page source].  You might have better luck accessing their API https://sites.google.com/site/grouponapiv2/home

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the selectnodes returns nothing or null when no nodes are found instead of an empty collection. so this means you should probably wrap `if (content_block != null) {` around your code block above.

Comment: yeah, but then it does not display anything, the HtmlNodeCollection seems to be empty, however i selected div node